# .htaccess dynamic 301 rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I convert some rewrite rules in .htaccess?
My old site had the following:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

which would rewrite url to : domain.com/some-page.html

Now I'm using different rewrite with virtual directories like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this translates into domain.com/page/somepage/

I have tried using

```
Redirect 301 some-page.html page/somepage/
```

but keep getting 404 error

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/$1 [L,R=301]
```